# ADT: GC overhead limit reached when running project with libraries in libs folder

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, adt, libraries

I have a problem with ADT, I get the error:

```
Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

When trying to run my project if the libraries are placed in the libs folder but if I place them in another place for example on the Desktop and then import them as external jars I dont get the error/crash.

How can I make it runnable with the libraries in the libs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that I got this error was because with the libraries I had included I exceeded the DVMs limit of number of methods.